# Точки после сокращений

Tags: орфография, сокращения

В каких случаях после сокращений слов ставятся точки, а в каких - нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точка не ставится только после сокращений мер и весов. Во всех остальных случаях точка ставится.
Примеры: *кг, мм, га; руб., тов. и т.д*.

Answer (score 3):

Кажется, у Розенталя указано, что после таких сокращений, как *млн* и *млрд*, также не требуется точки.

Comment: Потому что «млн» и «млрд» образованы путём выкидывания букв из середины, а не обрубания окончаний.

Answer (score 3):

> Точка не ставится только после сокращений мер и весов.

Не согласен. Не ставятся точки после сокращений СИ и некоторых других, общеупотребительных сокращений. Например, *кг*, *г*, *см*, *дл*, *моль*, *с*, *мин*, *ч* и пр. Точки ставятся в следующих случаях: *а. е.* (астрономическая единица), *л. с.* (лошадиная сила), *г.* (год), *мм рт. ст.* (мм ртутного столба, единица давления), *куб. м* (кубический метр, единица объема), *гр.* (градус) и пр.

Достаточно подробно правила расписаны [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/86-rubric-100). Не считаю нужным повторять все пункты.

P. S. Думаю, что все еще очень сильно зависит от характера текста. Например, российский рубль можно записать как RUR и такая запись в каких-нибудь экономических научных текстах, думаю, вполне допустима.

Answer (score 1):

Часы и минуты в современной орфграфии тоже без точек: 5 мин и 2 ч

Answer (score 0):

В цитируемой справке [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/86-rubric-100) для сокращения секунды предусматривается точка. Думаю на такие источники не стоит ссылаться.